# Tor Browser version 6 doesn't open on Win 7 64 bit; no error msg, also W10

Tags: windows

Tor Browser v 6 doesn't open at all with no error on screen or event viewer. Tried upgrading then a new install with no joy. Have had no issues running the last 7 or so versions. Ideas?

Security software in use: Microsoft Security Essentials plus Malwarebytes Pro Edition. Have uninstalled both with no joy. Additionally the last 7 or so versions of Tor Browser have worked with no problems whatsoever with same security solutions.

Comment: Do you have some specific anti-virus *"solution"* that might be causing problems? That's a pretty common cause of this sort of behaviour.

Comment: going low rent with Microsoft Security Essentials plus Malwarebytes Pro Edition. Have uninstalled both with no joy. Additionally the last 7 or so versions of Tor Browser have worked with no problems whatsoever with same security solutions

Comment: Next stage is to take a look in your Windows Event Logs under Applications, see if there are any errors about Tor Browser.

Comment: hey tyvm for replying. i did check the logs at the time and nothing in any of the Windows logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go back to the previous version, which was 5.5.5 I think. Here is a link I found. There may be many others of course.

https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/5.5.5/

When you start it, Tor will tell you this is out of date, but you will have to ignore that until a working 6.x is available.

Good luck.

Comment: https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/5.5.5/ would be a much better link, straight to the torproject's website but in general "downgrade" is a bad precedent to set. in this case there were no major firefox security vulnerabilities patched between the 5.5.5 and 6.0 but *normally* there are.

Comment: @canonizingironize Thanks for your comment. I changed the link in the above answer.

Comment: hey thanks i did find that version and have downloaded it but really im kinda bummed and have been just using firefox with a vpn for general browsing....would really like to find out what the issue is